# Macro HAVE_DECL_FORK

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I'm a new learner of bitcoin project. I'm aware that the macros in header file config/bitcoin-config.h and whole file itself were generated by autoconf. Looked into configure.ac, regarding to fork symbol, I only see only one check AC_CHECK_DECLS([fork]), i.e., I cannot find where symbol fork is defined, but in bitcoin-config.h value of macro HAVE_DECL_FORK is 1. This is true for some other symbols.
Could anyone help to explain that?

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/configure.ac

Answer (score 1):

Symbols like fork are system calls with APIs that are part of POSIX. Access to them are provided by the C library implementations via the `unistd.h` header.

If you look at the `AC_CHECK_DECLS` [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Generic-Declarations.html), it states that if the includes are not specified, then the [default includes](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.67/html_node/Default-Includes.html#Default-Includes) are used, and this includes `unistd.h`.

Comment: I got it, thanks @Andrew